# How to delete mariaDB's specified Connection_name for multi source replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have several replication settings on mariaDB(latest:10.1.8). Please make sure that I'm using `Multiple replication` not a legacy `Single replication`.

I've added some settings with `CHANGE MASTER "blah" TO` command. Now I'd like to remove just one of them from `show all slaves status`.

```
mysql -e "show all slaves status\G;" | grep "Connection_name\|Running"
              Connection_name: 
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: asi.exapmle.com
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: bee.exapmle.com
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: dild.exapmle.com
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: datr.exapmle.com
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: db.exapmle.com
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: nop.exapmle.com
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

How can I delete only `db.exapmle.com` from this replication list without  getting a effect to other replications?

Answer (score 8):

### Finally I found the solution!

`RESET SLAVE 'Connection_name' all` was what I wanted. 
Not just `RESET SLAVE`, **you need to add `ALL` at the end**.

> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reset-slave-connection_name/

```
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "show all slaves status\G;" | grep "Connection_name\|Running"
              Connection_name:              # <- empty name and wanna remove
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: wanna-remove-db       # <- wanna remove
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: wanna-keep-db         # <- don't wanna remove '
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "STOP SLAVE 'wanna-remove-db';"
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "RESET SLAVE 'wanna-remove-db' all;" 
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "show all slaves status\G;" | grep "Connection_name\|Running"
              Connection_name: 
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Connection_name: wanna-keep-db
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "STOP SLAVE ''"
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "RESET SLAVE '' all;" 
[root@maria ~]# mysql -e "show all slaves status\G;" | grep "Connection_name\|Running"
              Connection_name: wanna-keep-db
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to your slave (db.exapmle.com) and execute a `STOP SLAVE` command.

If you don't have access to the slave you need to blacklist, e.g. by revoking GRANTS for the slave user. Latter one will still allow the slave to connect but not to authenticate (so you should consider to disallow connect by using e.g. iptables).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I can stop the replication with `STOP SLAVE` but I don't want to see those settings in `SHOW ALL SLAVE STATUS` again. (My replication monitoring service will alert it if there are those stopped connection_name yet. I can specify only alive connectoin_names for the monitoring but it's not a good way. )